# How do I style <embed> tags in CSS stylesheets?

Tags: css

Why can't I style embed tags in CSS? For example, I want to override the width of all YouTube videos on my site my (which are currently 630px) to 600px. I tried doing the following, but it doesn't work. My text editor (Sublime Text 2) doesn't even seem to syntax highlight embed tags in CSS:

```
img, video, object, embed {
max-width: 100%;    
height: auto;
}
```

Lack of syntax color highlighting in Sublime Text 2. Does this essentially mean you can't style embed tags in CSS stylesheets? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NQ1q.png

Answer (score 2):

Embedded elements typically have their `[height]` and `[width]` attributes defined inline:

```
<embed height="300" width="400" ... />
```

Inline styles (including these attributes) take precedence over CSS rules (they're more like *suggestions* really).